# Making a Laravel 5.4 query on a JSON field containing a JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, laravel

i'm trying to query a JSON field containing an array of values.
For exemple sake we'll name the table "**User**" and the field "**Friends**". Here's how the Friends field looks like :

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "img": "img-1.jpg",
    "name": "Name 1"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "img": "img-2.jpg",
    "name": "Name 2"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "img": "img-3",
    "name": "Name 3"
}]
```

So what I would like to do is **on the User table query everything from the Friends field where there is an id equals to 3**.

So something like : `User::where('friends->id', 3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`
Of course, the exemple above works perfectly if the field did not contain an array, so if it was just :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "img": "img-1.jpg",
    "name": "Name 1"
}
```

Desperate, and even though I know it's not very logical, I have tried with "whereIn" : `User::whereIn('friends->id', [3])->get()`. Or stuff like : `User::where('friends->[0]->id', 3)->get()`, `User::where('friends->[*]->id', 3)->get()`, `User::where('friends->*->id', 3)->get()`.

I have also tried with *JSON_CONTAINS* or *JSON_SEARCH* : `User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(friends->"$.id", "3")')->get()` and many different variants but nothing does it.

Before coming here I have read a few interesting articles on the matter (they are listed bellow), but I seem to be the only one who have ever stored a JSON array in a MySQL database, how is that possible ? ^^

- https://mattstauffer.com/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3/
- https://themsaid.com/laravel-mysql-json-colum-fast-lookup-20160709
- http://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/

So if anyone could help me solve this problem I would really appreciate it.
Side notes :  my current MySQL version is 5.7.11, so it does support JSON fields and Laravel doesn't throw any errors, it just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `whereRaw` attempt is very close. If you were storing a single object, your path would be `$.id`. However, since you're storing an array of objects, your path is `$[*].id`. This should work for you:

```
User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(friends->"$[*].id", "3")')->get();
```

The `friends->"$[*].id"` selector (which is just a shortcut for `JSON_EXTRACT()`) will return a json array of the ids. `JSON_CONTAINS()` will then check if that json array contains the specified id.

Another option would be to build a json search string to use for `JSON_CONTAINS()`. For example, this query should also work:

```
User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(friends, \'{"id": 3}\')')->get();
```

This avoids the first call to `JSON_EXTRACT()`, so you're only calling one json method. I do not know which version would actually be faster, or if there would be any difference.

Also, on a side note related to `JSON_SEARCH()`, this function will only work if you are searching for string values. Since your json shows that the ids are represented as integers instead of strings, `JSON_SEARCH()` will not work. MySQL claims this is intended behavior ([bug 79233](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233) and [dup bug 79316](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79316)).

Just for reference, [here is the documentation for the json search methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: You sir, have just made my day ! Thank you very much.
**Both of your solutions works**, I will probably be using the latter one as I find it more elegant, more JSON-like and call for only one json method.

Again thank you for your very straight forward but complete answer.

Comment: Since Laravel 5.6.24, you can use `whereJsonContains()`: `User::whereJsonContains('friends', ['id' => 3])->get();`