# Laravel 5.4 query on a JSON field containing a JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Inside users table I have a json column named "agencies" that stores data as a simple array like this:

```
[
"0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12",
"f7c748d4-8718-441e-aa69-91b890ead5ed"
],
```

the above is valid json. When I try to select all users that contain `0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12` I get null

Is my query correct?

```
$users = User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(agencies->"$[*]", "0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12")')->get();
```

is the below correct way to do  write JSON select query conbsidering how I store uuids as an array inside agencies column which is defined as json?

```
'JSON_CONTAINS(agencies->"$[*]", "0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12"
```

I got the idea for above select from reading: [Making a Laravel 5.4 query on a JSON field containing a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016520/making-a-laravel-5-4-query-on-a-json-field-containing-a-json-array)

but the solution in that post is different then what I am trying to do and my modification to it does not give me back any users, but instead I allways get null back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's what you want:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(agencies, ?)', ['0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12'])->get();
```

It will also soon be supported with the query builder. [See PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24330)

Comment: that looked like it would be the right syntax, but I still got null back. Wonder why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects a JSON string:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(agencies, ?)',
    ['"0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12"'])->get();
$users = User::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(agencies, ?)',
    [json_encode('0eb2edf0-50cb-44ff-a0a6-b2a104a9dc12')])->get();
```