# Find element in array from column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, laravel

I have a table "Notifications". In my data column, I have an array-like:

```
{  
   "title":"Something",
   "arr":{  
      "id":12,
      "name":"HelloWorld",
      "avatar":null
   }
}
```

And I want to check element (notify) which `arr->id == 12` for example (or something else).
I tryed make query buildng but nothing works. Examples:

```
$hello = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('notifiable_id', Auth::user()->id)
                             ->where('data', '%12%')->first();
```

**or**

```
$hello = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('notifiable_id', Auth::user()->id)
                              ->where('data->arr->id', '12')->first();
```

Who knows how do that?

Comment: `data` column is JSON or VARCHAR?

Comment: Example of data column you have in first code block. If you think about type of column, it's a text

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ..SELECT JSON_SEARCH(......) for more reference you can refer this link [How to search JSON array in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249828/how-to-search-json-array-in-mysql)

Comment: forHow can I do that in Laravel for query building?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help:

```
$arr = 'arr';
$id = 'id';
$hello = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('notifiable_id', Auth::user()->id)->where("data->{$arr}->{$id}", '12')->first();
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, but in case you still stuck with this problem, I think further link help you       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016520/making-a-laravel-5-4-query-on-a-json-field-containing-a-json-array